# Name columns of file.txt

Tags: python

I have `file.txt` with five columns and 50 lines. I want to name each column

```
1 5
2 4.2
. .
. .
```

Comment: I see only two columns. What names do you want to give the columns?

Comment: I like to name each column for example first column leaveTime, second column ReportTime

Comment: This looks very unrelated to python, in fact the original issue can be solved in notepad. Please post a programming question along with what you tried to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

you find here the code python ton generate file.txt

```
f = open("test_01.txt", "a")
    for i in xrange(len(end_zapstart_zap)):
        f.write(" {} {} {} {} {} \n".format(Leavestart_zap[i],end_zapUDP[i],end_zapstart_zap[i],Leave_join[i],UDP_join[i]))
    f.close()
```

I like to rename the first column Leavestart_zap,the seond column end_zapUDP etc..
here is my file test_01.txt:

0:00:00.672511 0:00:02.615662 0:00:03.433344 0:00:00.119777 0:00:00.025394 0:00:00.002278
 0:00:00.263144 0:00:03.184893 0:00:03.541187 0:00:00.090872 0:00:00.025394 0:00:00.002278